# No sound from front speakers Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, speakers

I have Lenovo Ideapad 14IRH8 (2023), it has 4 speakers - 2 on the bottom side of the laptop and 2 on the front. Two speakers on the back side works fine, but main front speakers are not working. Maybe I have to install some additional drivers